# DNS and Domain Pointing

Tags: hosting, dns

I'm a newbie at DNS and would like to know how to point a domain to a host, when the domain and hosting are from different sites. I bought my domain at 1and1.com and my hosting plan from ipower.com

Comment: SO is for programing questions. this is a networking question. There are plans for building a networking related SO however until it is ready you should ask this question in other sites. Thanks

Comment: You should really ask your provider for help. In your case, you pay money to two different parties, so get them to sort your problem!

Comment: "how to point a domain to a host" is vague. You mean you want the Web server to be hosted at ipower.com? If so, first talk to ipower.com (or read their documentation) and see what is the IP address you have to indicate in the DNS.

Comment: I think the General IT version of SO will launch as soon as they settle on the logo, until then .. unfortunately this is not programming related.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible methods;

Move all the DNS records for your domain to ipower or just create a single A record for www in the DNS at 1and1.

To move the DNS records to ipower you will need to know the address of their name servers.

To set up the DNS on 1and1 servers to point to your web space, you will need to know the ip address of the server your web space will be hosted on.

Either way your best bet is to talk to ipower.

Answer (score 0):

1and1 has an administration area for you to edit your domain's name servers.

These name servers will be provided by 1power.com

Comment: So basically I go to 1and1's admin area, and input the nameservers from ipower, which are usually ns1.ipower.com, and ns2.ipower.com for the secondary nameserver? Will the nameservers be unique or these generic ones?

Comment: There seems to be an issue when I do this. I go to my site which is at msa-roch.com, and I get an error, as well as an IP address instead of a URL in the address bar. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: The answer is wrong: there is no need to host the Web server (which is probably what the OP was talking about) with the same provider as the DNS servers. You can certainly edit the DNS data on 1&1 panel and gives an IP address indicated by the Web hoster.

Answer (score 0):

The Web server at ipower.com has not been configured for msa-roch.com (may be because you did not ask ipower to do so) and contains just an HTML redirection (awful technique, it indicates that this company is not tech-savvy):

```
% telnet msa-roch.com http
Trying 66.96.130.149...
Connected to msa-roch.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: msa-roch.com
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2009 07:39:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Mon, 16 Feb 2009 18:21:28 GMT
ETag: "b5f696af-5f-4630d414dfc69"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 95

<HTML> <HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; url=http://74.208.128.239">  </HEAD> </HTML> Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This redirection explains what you see. Talk to ipower.com or read their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience using domain names (registered with 1and1) with dreamhost hosting.

You can easily achieve what you want with the following steps:

1. configure your hosting plan for your domain. Even if this domain is not available in your domain pool, you should be able to host it.
2. Look for the IP associated with this domain in your hosting web panel.
3. Edit your DNS configuration in 1and1 web panel and set the "A" entry to the IP you just looked up.
4. Wait for DNS propagation and test.

This solution may not work all the time; if you don't have a static IP in your hosting package, your hosting company *could* move this domain from one server to another (thus changing the IP).

I never faced this situation, but still, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for hosting at Dreamhost with a domain at 1and1:

1. Dreamhost > Manage Domains > Add New Domain > Fully Hosted
2. 1and1 > Domains > check the box of the domain > DNS > Edit DNS Settings:

> ```
> name server: my name server
> Primary name server: ns1.dreamhost.com
> Secondary name server : my secondary name server 
> One Secondary name server: ns2.dreamhost.com
> Two Secondary name server: ns3.dreamhost.com
> ```

Then wait an hour or two for the changes to propagate through the systems.